# Integrating $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$ using $u$-substitution with an $x$ left over after?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> $$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx.$$

When I use $u$-substitution to get the indefinite integral of that function, I get an extra $x$ on my $du$. How can I deal with that $x$?

This is what I got: $\frac{1}{2}du = x \, dx$

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @probablyme Thanks a lot!

Comment: The usual substitution is $x=\sin\theta$, or if you prefer (I don't) $\theta=\arcsin x$.

Comment: Problems like this need [trigonometric substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u$-substitution *could* work, but as Tim said it is much easier to just recognize that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ is the derivative of an inverse trig function.

If you insist on using $u$-sub, you can always write $x=\sin\theta$, so that $dx=\cos \theta \,d\theta$. Then, $\sqrt{1-x^2} = \sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta} = \cos\theta$, so that our problem is just: $$\int\frac{dx}{\cos\theta}=\int\frac{\cos\theta \, d\theta}{\cos\theta} = \int1 \, d\theta = \theta + C = \arcsin(x) + C$$

Comment: I want to understand how do we get  sin θ in place of x? What is the underlaying step for that conversion? Would you please further explain that?

Comment: There is the famous identity $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$, so in particular $\cos^2 \theta = 1-\sin^2 \theta$. Things in the form $1-x^2$ generally lend themselves nicely to trig. Also, $\tan^2 \theta + 1 = \sec^2 \theta$.

Also, $\sin$ and $\cos$ are derivatives of each other (the derivative of cosine is negative sine, but they're kind of the same), so $u$-substitution lends itself well here, too. That's the motivation, at least.

Answer (score 1):

$u$ substitution will not work for this problem.  You need to recognize that $1/\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is the derivative of an inverse trig function.

Comment: So, do you mean that whenever I get an extra variable inside my `du` that doesn't exist in my original function, I can't use U-substitution? And how would I solve it otherwise?